# Pandas: set the value of a column in a row to be the value stored in a different df at the index of its other rows

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df
   0  1
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  2  1
>>> df1
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  D  E  F
>>> crazy_magic()
>>> df
   0  1  3
0  0  0  A #df1[0][0]    
1  1  1  E #df1[1][1]
2  2  1  F #df1[2][1]
```

Is there a way to achieve this without `for`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[1,1],[2,1]])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'],['D', 'E', 'F']])

df2 = df1.reset_index(drop=False)
#    index  0  1  2
# 0      0  A  B  C
# 1      1  D  E  F

df3 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['index'])
#    index variable value
# 0      0        0     A
# 1      1        0     D
# 2      0        1     B
# 3      1        1     E
# 4      0        2     C
# 5      1        2     F

result = pd.merge(df, df3, left_on=[0,1], right_on=['variable', 'index'])
result = result[[0, 1, 'value']]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   0  1 value
0  0  0     A
1  1  1     E
2  2  1     F
```

---

My reasoning goes as follows:

We want to use two columns of `df` as coordinates.

The word "coordinates" reminds me of `pivot`, since
if you have two columns whose values represent "coordinates" and a third
    column representing values, and you want to convert that to a grid, then
    pivot is the tool to use.

But `df` does not have a third column of values. The values are in `df1`. In fact `df1` looks like the result of a `pivot` operation. So instead of pivoting `df`, we want to unpivot `df1`.

`pd.melt` is the function to use when you want to unpivot.

So I tried melting `df1`. Comparison with other uses of `pd.melt` led me to conclude `df1` needed the index as a column. That's the reason for defining `df2`. So we melt `df2`.

Once you get that far, visually comparing `df3` to `df` leads you naturally to the use of `pd.merge`.